# Listen for urls and redirect

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an iOS app that wraps around a website. What I want to do is catch certain redirects via their URL and redirect them to a different URL with a query string appended.

Something like:

```
if(url) {
    url = newUrl + "?foo=bar";
}
```

Comment: You are using UIWebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a UIWebView delegate method for this.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:url]) 
    {
        url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?foo=bar", url];
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late now but I would use the `webViewDidFinishLoad` and the `webViewDidStartLoad` delegate methods to detect redirects as follows:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    myRequestedUrl= [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"Requested url: %@", myRequestedUrl);    // that is (url = url + "?foo=bar")
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{  

    myLoadedUrl = [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"Loaded url: %@", myLoadedUrl);
}
```

I hope this helps you...
All the best!!!